# why do I find (under /proc/pid//fd) sockets with broken symlinks

Tags: linux, proc, socket

I don't think they're closed, because I would expect that after a close() the fd would disappear, but I see a bunch of lingering fd -> socket[xxxxx] entries with broken symlinks which don't seem to be going away quickly.  What causes this state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The socket[xxxxx] symlinks are always broken.  There is no path you can access in order to open a socket with a given inode number.

I tried it, and it seems you cannot open the file `/proc/pidX/fd/Y` which refers to a socket.  However you can if it refers to a real file, even if the file has been deleted.  It is not exactly a symlink. It is magic - i.e. a special case.

Comment: Why I can't see neither `/proc/fd` nor `/proc/pid`? Are they available in newer Linux kernels?

Comment: typo, sorry.  Answer updated.

Comment: Ok, pid is the process id of the process and not the word "pid". It is useful to mention this.

Comment: Some do not show up as broken symlinks, a fairly large number don't.  Why don;t they all show up that way like you indicate?  Is it only unix domain socket that have a an actual sock file like ones under /tmp or /var ?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: How may I get detail information from the broken sockets,  say what causes these unclosed fd?

Comment: The *sockets* are not broken. The entries in this question represent open sockets. They do not mean anything has gone wrong. // However, the entries for open sockets are always shown as "broken symlinks". A "broken symlink" is a symlink that points to a filename which does not exist. In addition, these are Linux "magic" symlinks. _Some_ "magic" symlinks in /proc can be opened even though they point to a filename which does not exist. However, these symlinks that represent open sockets, can not be opened,

Comment: If you have a question about sockets which you think *should* be closed for some reason, but which have not been closed, I highly recommend writing a new question. Feel free to link it to me here.

Answer (score 4):

The text of the symlink destination does not refer to a file, but to an entry in the `/proc/net/tcp` table that describes each socket using encoded text fields. For example, on my system at the moment I see:

```
$ ls -l /proc/24724/fd/7
lrwx------ 1 vagrant vagrant 64 Feb 13 15:08 /proc/24724/fd/7 -> socket:[19164451]
```

Which corresponds to this line from the `tcp` table:

```
$ grep 19164451 /proc/net/tcp
 433: 0100007F:C8AA 0100007F:0C8A 01 00000000:00000000 02:00000286 00000000  1000        0 19164451 2 0000000000000000 20 4 1 10 27
```

Some quick Google searches should help you find numerous resources for decoding these lines. Two examples:

http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/linux/2000/11/16/LinuxAdmin.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992211/list-of-possible-internal-socket-statuses-from-proc

If you instead want a tool that processes them for you, `netstat` will do it if you use the `-p` option to tell it to read all of your `/proc` `fd` links to learn which processes belong to which sockets. Try:

```
netstat -tuapn
```